# Laravel Eloquent Error (SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried to retrieve data by joining 3 table using below queries but it returns the above error (in the title). I couldn't discover what's the problem. Thank you in advance.

```php
$data = DB::connection('pgsql_backoffice')
            ->table('tusers')
            ->join('tservices','tusers.user_id','=','tservices.user_id')
            ->join('tnotify_send_info','tnotify_send_info.user_id','=','tnotify_send_info.user_id')
            ->select('tusers.user_id','tservices.account_no','tusers.cust_type','tusers.first_name','tusers.last_name','tusers.company_name','tservices.created_t','tservices.start_t','tnotify_send_info.notify_actual_date')
            ->where('tservices.plan_id','tnotify_send_info.package_id')
            ->get();
```

The error says that there are something wrong with 'tnotify_send_info.package_id'

Comment: Can you show us the full error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereColumn()` to compare columns:

```php
->whereColumn('tservices.plan_id', 'tnotify_send_info.package_id')
```